# Maximum recursion depth exceeded on simple loop

Tags: python, pandas, loops, recursion

I am trying to create a pretty straight forward loop that sorts through about 900 nested dictionaries and returns all of the values in lists named after the keys. I am getting the following recursion error though:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in myprint
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in myprint
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in myprint
  [Previous line repeated 995 more times]
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in myprint
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

Here's the code I'm currently using:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("/Users/--/--/--/--/--/.csv")
def myprint(d):
    for k, v in data.items():
            if isinstance(v, dict):
                myprint(v)
            else:
                print("{0} : {1}".format(k, v))
                setattr(sys.modules[__name__], k, [v])
            
            
for i in df['file_num']:
    with open("/Users/--/--/--/--/allDAFs{}.json".format(i)) as f:
        data=json.load(f)
    myprint(data)
```

I would greatly appreciate any potential insight into how this can be fixed or worked around. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is this loop `for k, v in data.items():` gets called every time you call the function.

I think you made the typo `data.items` instead of `d.items`

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("/Users/--/--/--/--/--/.csv")
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("/Users/--/--/--/--/--/.csv")
def myprint(d):
#   for k, v in data.items():
    for k, v in d.items():
            if isinstance(v, dict):
                myprint(v)
            else:
                print("{0} : {1}".format(k, v))
                setattr(sys.modules[__name__], k, [v])
            
            
for i in df['file_num']:
    with open("/Users/--/--/--/--/allDAFs{}.json".format(i)) as f:
        data=json.load(f)
    myprint(data)
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is doing what it's intended to do though. If the value is a dict it unwraps it further a layer until it is either a string or integer. This is necessary since I have a pretty heavily nested dictionary. Also the loop is the entirety of the function so I don't see how you can move it out without deleting the function.

Comment: You were unwrapping the initial dictionary `data` every time instead of the parameter `d`

Comment: If op confirms it's only Typo. I will close this thread.

Comment: I worked it out, not even sure how. Please close thread. @Wimanicesir Thank you for the contributions

Answer (score 0):

check if your program works for one recursion. then
if u want to increase your recursion limit you can do this

```
sys.setrecursionlimit(2000)
```